# Is the set $n: n=10k$ for some k in integers closed under addition? is it associative? identity? Inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the set $\{n: n=10k \text{ for some } k \in \Bbb Z\}$ closed under addition? is it associative? identity? Inverse?

I believe that it is closed under addition since the addition of factors of $10$ are also divisible by $10$.

I also believe it is to be associative.
I'm struggling on how to show that is has an identity and an inverse though

Comment: Your argument for closure is hard to follow.  Suppose you have two multiples of $10$, call them $10n$ and $10m$ .  What is their sum?  Can you show that their sum is again a multiple of $10$?

Comment: Well, any factor of 10 would be divisible by 10

Comment: No, that's not true.  $5$ is a factor of $10$ and it is not divisible by $10$.

Comment: I meant multiple, not factor. So then is this asking if we have 2 multiples of 10, say 30 and 40, would the addition of the two then be divisible by that multiple?

Comment: Well, again, you are using words in a very confusing way.  When you say "divisible by that multiple", which multiple are you talking about?

Comment: Keep in mind:  mathematical arguments are nothing if they are not clear and precise.  All you are asked to show, in this first part, is that the sum of two multiples of $10$ is, again, a multiple of $10$.

Comment: "I meant multiple, not factor."  It's *very* important that you use the right words.  Your argument is good for the meanings you said.  But using the wrong words, you might as well have said all the elements are made of cheese.

Comment: well then the answer would be yes, since every multiple of 10, when added together, will still be a multiple of 10

Comment: But, that's exactly what you have to prove!  You can't argue that "this set is closed under addition because it is closed under addition."  That said, all you need to do here is to remark that $10\times n+10\times m=10\times (n+m)$.

Comment: And is it true that $(10n + 10m) + 10j = 10n + (10m +10j)$.  And can you solve for $10e$:  $10m + 10e = 10m$ and once you solve for $e$ can you solve for $10k$: $10m + 10k =0$.

Comment: @lulu That makes complete sense and I understand the theory, I just do not know how to say it in math language. I'm not sure how to get practice doing that

Comment: Well, you need to say if $10n$ is a multiple of $10$ and $10m$ is a multiple of $10$, then you have to show that there is a multiple $10K$ so that $10n + 10m = 10K$.  And that's simply a matter of noting $10n + 10m =10(n+m)$.  Now to prove it is associative you must prove that $(10n + 10m) + 10j =10n + (10m+10j)$ always.  That's true because the addition is always associative.  Now, is there a $10e$ so that $10m + 10e =10m$ always?  That's what you must do to prove there is an identity.

Comment: if e=0. Identity under addition tends to be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G= \{10n~\vert~n \in \Bbb Z \}$ be the set of integer multiples of $10$.

**Claim:**  $G$ is closed under addition, addition is associative in $G$, $G$ has an additive identity and $G$ is closed under additive inverses.

**Proof:**  Assume $x, y \in G$.  Then $\exists m, n \in \Bbb Z$ with $x=10m, y=10n$.  Then $x+y=10m+10n=10(m+n)$, and $m, n \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow m+n \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow x+y \in G$, so $G$ is closed under addition.

Addition is associative in $G$ because it is associative in $\Bbb Z$, and $G \subseteq \Bbb Z$.

$0=10 \times 0 \in G.  \forall x \in G~(x+0=0)$ so $G$ has an additive identity; namely, $0$.

Finally, assume $x =10m \in G$.  Then $m \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow -m \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow 10(-m)=-10m = -x \in G$.  Of course $x+(-x)=0$ so $G$ is closed under additive inverses.